# Adding a border and shadow to a nib initiated view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I am making a subclass of **UIViewController** which, when the user pressed a button, will initiate and add a view from another **UIViewController** subclass.

Inside the added view I have an instance of **UIWebView** and **UIButton** (for closing the popup).

Since it is intended as a pop up, I want to add a border and a shadow to the **UIWebView**, but since it is nib initiated, I don't know how I can modify the drawing code.

Any help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at using the view's `CALayer`.

To add a border:

```
myView.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
myView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

There are similar methods for adding a shadow:

```
myView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(4.f, 4.f);
myView.layer.shadowRadius = 4.f;
myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
myView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

You will need to add the Quartz framework to your target, and import the header in your controller's .m file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: Aha! So it is incorporated in the UIView classes already! Thanks heaps! :)
But what difference does the last line make? Bitmap or no bitmap?

Comment: The `shouldRasterize` property being set to `YES` can improve the performance of adding a shadow.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **Border** and **Shadow** to any control in this way.
 You can also set **Width** of **Border** and can also make it **Rounded**.

```
CALayer * l1 = [viewPopup layer];
[l1 setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l1 setCornerRadius:5.0];

// Add a border
[l1 setBorderWidth:5.0];
[l1 setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];

// Add a shadow
[l1 setShadowColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
[l1 setShadowOpacity:5.0];
// You can more methods for shadow
```

Just replace `viewPopup` with your control.

**Note:-** Don't forget to import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`